# Gutenberg Custom Style problem with background image

Tags: block-editor

When calls theme's **style.css** file with `add_editor_style` inside gutenberg, background images are not loading properly.

Lets say:

```
#intro {
    background: url(assets/main.png) ;
}
```

Its working properly on front-end like:

```
mydomain.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/assets/main.png
```

But when in gutenberg, WordPress tries to load:

```
mydomain.com/wp-admin/assets/main.png
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: Is there a reason you do not want to set the full relative path in style.css? Have you tried `#intro { background: url('/wp-content/themes/mytheme/assets/main.png') ;}`

Comment: It can be in subfolder installation

Answer (score 0):

You can load the css via PHP instead ,

```
add_action('wpmm_head', 'wpmm_custom_css');

    function wpmm_custom_css(){
     echo '<style>
           #intro{
    '.get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/main.png;
           }
           </style>';
    }
```

Comment: You can't always know all images tbh. This is a problem that needs automatic fix